# Has customtabs mayLaunchUrl behaviour changed?

Tags: android, google-chrome, chromium, chrome-custom-tabs, android-customtabs

I used to use the chrome CustomTabs mayLaunchUrl in my app to request a URL in the background and as a result drop the desired cookie in the users chrome browser, but now that I'm testing this feature again, I noticed it doesn't work the same way anymore and the URL is not requested by the CustomTabs library anymore when I call the mayLaunchUrl  method. is it a recent change in the library or the chrome app? or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As it's said in [Chrome docs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs#bestpractices),

> Custom Tabs is smart and knows if the user is using the phone on a metered network or if it’s a low end device and pre-rendering will have a negative effect on the overall performance of the device and won’t pre-fetch or pre-render on those scenarios. So, there’s no need to optimize your application for those cases.

It means that in some cases Custom Tabs will not do request (and there are lots of these cases as I can see — on my device it does not request anything too).

Comment: it was a long time ago when I was working with this but I remember I had tried this on fast wifi connection with relatively new phones (nexus 4 etc) and it wasn't droping cookie, might be this that you mentioned but also something else.\